# How to recursively export all from folders in node js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my React JS project I have configured a `jsconfig.json` such that I can recursively export nested directories and import a specific export from the base directory as follows:

`jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

Project folder structure:

```
react-app
  src
    common
    index.js
      services
        ServiceA.js
        ServiceB.js
        index.js
      components
        ComponentA.jsx
        index.js
    pages
      pageA
        PageA.jsx
        index.js
    App.jsx
    index.js
```

Now in each `index.js` I would export all from each file/folder. So for example in `common/services/index.js`:

```js
export * from 'common/services/ServiceA.js';
export * from 'common/services/ServiceB.js';
```

And in `common/index.js`:

```js
export * from 'common/services';
export * from 'common/components';
```

Now if I require `ServiceA` exported from `ServiceA.js` in the `PageA.jsx` file I could import it as follows:

```js
// PageA.jsx
import {
  ServiceA
} from 'common';
```

```js
// ServiceA.js
export class ServiceA {
  doStuff () {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

How can I setup my NodeJS server project to allow for similar exports and imports?

I'd like to do this for consistency between the FE and BE such that I can easily port over any FE code to my BE project without having to make any significant changes to exports and imports.

**Edit:** I managed to get it working using the answer by Besworks to which I awarded the bounty, however VS Code Intellisense wouldn't navigate to the export definition from the import statement until I added a `jsconfig.json` in the project root:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "#common" : ["./common/index.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [map exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns) in your `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "@your-namespace/your-package",
  ...
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./common": "./common/index.js"
  }
}
```

Then you can refer to the exports by name :

```
import { YourClass } from '@your-namespace/your-package';
import { AnotherClass } from '@your-namespace/your-package/common';
```

Alternatively, if your submodules only need to be accessible from within your package, you could map `imports` instead of `exports` which would not need your package name prepended but must start with a `#` character. You don't need to explicitly specify each submodule either, you can map everything from within a folder with wildcard substitution :

```
{
  "name": "your-package",
  ...
  "imports": {
    "#common": "./common/index.js",
    "#common/services": "./common/services/index.js",
    "#common/services/*": "./common/services/*.js",
    "#shortcut": "./deeply/nested/path/to/module.js"
  }
}
```

And use them :

```
import { YourClass } from '#common';
import * from '#common/services';
import { AnotherClass } from '#common/services/ServiceA';
import something from '#shortcut';
```

In the above example, `#common` would be a reference to `./common/index.js` and `#common/services/ServiceA` would point to `./common/services/ServiceA.js`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but is this the only way, also if I have multiple levels of nested folders, e.g. /services within common I would also have to add ./common/services/index.js to exports and similarly for any other folders, also I have to prepend all imports with @{namespace}. Is it not possible to work with exports&imports like I do in my ReactJS projects?

Comment: I updated my answer with information about mapping `imports` rather than `exports`, this might be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, presumably I'll have to change type to module to work with import and export

Comment: Also I don't want to necessarily import from nested folders(e.g. ./common/services) explicitly but simply import from ./common which exports from all nested folders/files recursively as I described in my question.

Comment: So just add `"#common/*": "./common/*/index.js"` to `imports`. Then you can access any path below ./common/ like `#common/deeply/nested/module` which will point to `./common/deeply/nested/module/index.js`

Comment: I pushed a full [working example](https://github.com/besworks/submodule-mapping) to github.

Comment: Much appreciated, is there a reason you didn't `export * from ./deep` in /services/index.js ?

Comment: I did it that way to show that you can access deeply nested paths directly without needing to export them at the intermediate layer.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working, I'll wait a few days to see if anyone has a better way of doing it before awarding the bounty

Comment: I think the biggest issue I have atm is that I can't easily navigate to the definition of whatever was imported in vs code.

Comment: That sounds like the topic for another question.

Comment: True, it's a non-issue in my react projects as I don't have to prepend import paths with #

Comment: Another issue is that VS Code doesn't auto suggest/complete class methods

Comment: I cannot help you with any vs code related issues. This method of import/export mapping has been around since Node v12, if Microsoft has not implemented support by now that is a failure on their part and has no bearing on the validity of my answer.

Comment: @MShakeG If I’ll recall, VS code uses typescript to support its JavaScript navigation. Typescript implemented the package exports support around 4.7. Looks like the next release of VS code will have it in, else you can install a newer version of typescript and point the intellisense to use that (either globally or locally).

Comment: I see, thanks, does it also support package imports? or just exports?

Answer (score 1):

If your node project is using `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, then the filestructure is exactly the same. However, importing from index files in ES modules is still behind an experimental flag:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#customizing-esm-specifier-resolution-algorithm

So you would have to launch it with e.g.:

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node src/index.js
```

---

```
$ tree src/
src/
├── common
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── ServiceA.js
│   └── ServiceB.js
├── index.js
└── other
    ├── index.js
    ├── OtherA.js
    └── OtherB.js
```

`src/index.js`

```js
import { serviceA, serviceB } from './common';
import { otherA, otherB } from './other';

serviceA();
serviceB();
otherA();
otherB();
```

`src/common/index.js`

```js
export * from './ServiceA';
export * from './ServiceB';
```

`src/common/ServiceA.js'

```js
export const serviceA = () => console.log('***** ServiceA');
```

Comment: Note that you'll still need the relative path between the modules. In your react projects, babel and/or webpack are taking all of your files and cramming them into (conceptually) one big file, so the relationship between paths on disk is wiped out completely. This is fundamentally different with node, as the file structure is maintained on the production server. You **can** use webpack for node projects too, if you like, but personally I wouldn't if the only reason is to avoid a few `../..`.